# using functions in code behind on webpage

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, so I'm figuring it out as I go along.

I'm trying to output the results of a function in my code behind page on the webpage itself.

Example:

Code Behind:

```
public string POSTResult(string e) { ... return TheResult; }
```

ASPX Page:

```
Output is: <%=POSTResult("argument")%>
```

However, loading the page errors, saying "The name 'POSTResult' does not exist in the current context."

I'm apparently doing something a bit off with how I'm getting to the code behind page from the ASPX page. My ASPX page has this at the top:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bitfork.login" %>
```

The listed CodeBehind value is the name of the code behind page.

ETA:

Contents of my code behind (login.aspx.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Bitfork.master
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string POSTResult(string e)
        {
            // variables to store parameter values
            string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

            // creates the post data for the POST request
            string postData = (e);

            // create the POST request
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            // POST the data
            using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                requestWriter2.Write(postData);
            }

            //  This actually does the request and gets the response back
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            string responseData = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return responseData;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of argument being passed, with API secret keys redacted:

```
code=[redacted]&client_id=[redacted]&client_secret=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:60284/login.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code
```

ETA2:

I don't know if it's related, but it seems like my code behind page and my webpage are not communicating with each other at all. For instance, I can't access DIVs by ID in my code behind page to change their contents.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you post all of your code-behind (`login.aspx.cs`)?

Comment: John - I didn't know that. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: if I use CodeBehind="~/login.aspx.cs" it works, if I leave out the ~/ it doesn't. Is this a setting or something I need to update?

Comment: Is this a website or web application?